# Forms: question vs. imperative mood

Tags: copywriting

When prompting the user to choose from a set of options, which of the following 2 ways is best?

"Select the payment methods you accept"
[ ] Method 1
[ ] Method 2
[ ] Method 3

"Which payment methods do you accept?"
[ ] Method 1
[ ] Method 2
[ ] Method 3

Answer (score 1):

Is the User using the System or is the System using the User?

A System using the User would ask questions of the User. Whereas a User using a System would follow clear, concise instructions to carry out their tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of the form.

First: If the inputs are different which the user is going to submit then go for questions.

Second: Imperative moods is something which allows the user to relate well with the service has been provided by the process on a platform but as a user, I have done the mistake to give wrong feedback in terms of mood.
why because: That mood is just not related to platform services but it is related to my surroundings and different factors also.